# What is Docker registry 2.0 tls clientcas

Tags: ssl, docker-registry

Could someone please explain what the `clientcas` is for?

```yaml
http:
    addr: localhost:5000
    prefix: /my/nested/registry/
    secret: asecretforlocaldevelopment
    tls:
        certificate: /path/to/x509/public
        key: /path/to/x509/private
    clientcas:
      - /path/to/ca.pem
      - /path/to/another/ca.pem
    debug:
        addr: localhost:5001
```

Taken from:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/

Answer (score 2):

'clientcas' is for Certificate Authorities (CAs) that have signed the registry/client certificates.  Simply having the a key and a certificate isn't enough for authentication - although some CAs are built into your web browser or your OS, you will want to supply at least one CA to the registry that is authoritative in regards to the Server/Client certificates used by that registry and its clients.
If you use self-signed certificates, this will be the CA you used to do the signing (i.e., the one used to sign the CSR).

Answer (score 0):

Client certificates provide client authentication. You can control access by issuing client certificates to authorized clients.